# How to remove index of array

Tags: php, arrays

Following is my array.. and i want to remove keys of starting array like 0,1,2.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cart_id] => 71
            [product_id] => 33
            [u_id] => 7
            [size] => medium
            [color] => blue
            [quantity] => 1
            [vendor_id] => 4
            [country_id] => 1
            [product_category] => 1
            [product_name] => Black Dress
            [short_description] => Flying Doll Black Dress
            [detail_description] => lorem ipsum
            [price] => 2000
            [special_price] => 2000



        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cart_id] => 74
            [product_id] => 37
            [u_id] => 7
            [size] => medium
            [color] => blue
            [quantity] => 1
            [vendor_id] => 4
            [country_id] => 1
            [product_category] => 3
            [product_name] => Pink Skirt
            [short_description] => Lady Shop Skirt combo
            [detail_description] => lorem ipsum
            [price] => 3000
            [special_price] => 2100



        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cart_id] => 72
            [product_id] => 46
            [u_id] => 7
            [size] => medium
            [color] => blue
            [quantity] => 2
            [vendor_id] => 4
            [country_id] => 1
            [product_category] => 1
            [product_name] => Chirag
            [short_description] => Hello guys
            [detail_description] => How r u
            [price] => 200
            [special_price] => 120


        )
}
```

I want to remove [0].[1],[2] before start array.

and i want to a main array with these child array including.

I do not have more idea about it, someone know well then please help me thank you.

I want to remove 0,1,2  from json out put

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "0": {
            "cart_id": "71",
            "product_id": "33",
            "u_id": "7",
            "size": "medium",
            "color": "blue",
            "quantity": "1",
            "vendor_id": "4",
            "country_id": "1",
            "product_category": "1",
            "product_name": "Black Dress",
            "short_description": "Flying Doll Black Dress",
            "detail_description": "lorem ipsum",
            "price": "2000",
            "special_price": "2000",
            "productImages": [
                {
                    "image_id": "2",
                    "image": "http://192.168.0.123/zerototwo/images/productimage/15136761291.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "image_id": "21",
                    "image": "http://192.168.0.123/zerototwo/images/productimage/15144618151.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        "1": {
            "cart_id": "74",
            "product_id": "37",
            "u_id": "7",
            "size": "medium",
            "color": "blue",
            "quantity": "1",
            "vendor_id": "4",
            "country_id": "1",
            "product_category": "3",
            "product_name": "Pink Skirt",
            "short_description": "Lady Shop Skirt combo",
            "detail_description": "lorem ipsum",
            "price": "3000",
            "special_price": "2100",
            "productImages": [
                {
                    "image_id": "8",
                    "image": "http://192.168.0.123/zerototwo/images/productimage/15136770031.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "image_id": "9",
                    "image": "http://192.168.0.123/zerototwo/images/productimage/15136770032.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Json generate code

```
 header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What do you want the end product to look like?

Comment: It's not really clear what you ask, do you want to unset the Array?

Comment: i have mentioned my json out put , i only remov 0,1,2,

Comment: How are you generating that JSON? Where's your code?

Comment: I have mentioned json generate code

Comment: I don't think the array you've given us, run through that code snippet will give the JSON you've provided.

Comment: @JonStirling exactly... the print_r output doesn't match. Its missing things, and theres no reason why json_encode would turn numbered indexes into objects. (no logical reason I would assume lol)

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to remove indexes, how are you going to contain the child arrays if they are not indexed? You'll be left with an empty array unless you replace them with some other index value.

Comment: @Rasclatt Think the OPs question should probably have been why are they getting a JSON object rather than JSON array containing objects. They're not actually wanting to remove items from the array afaict.

Comment: and what was your failed attempt?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
$response= [ 'status' => true, 'data' => array_values($data) ] ;
echo json_encode($response);
```